# How to scroll a specific element in a scroll list (no option no select tag of html, just div tags)

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I created a custom dropdown list in ReactJs. (I don't want to use option or "select" tag of html because it's difficult to custom style of dropdown list)

The problem is how to scroll to a specific element? For example, we have a list of year 2000 - 2010, it's a scroll list (3 years visible). I want the first value selected is 2005, and after click "Select tab", list scrolls to that position right away.

Thank you for your time!

```
let choiceList = ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010"];
const startYears = choiceList.map((item, i) => (
 <div key={i} className="dropdown-item" onClick={() => setStart(item)}>
   {item}
 </div>
));
 
<Dropdown
 selectContent={selectStart}
 width="17.9rem"
 content={<div className="listItems">{startYears}</div>}
/>
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing website. Please post what you've attempted and people may try and help you.

Comment: Yes, I have a dropdown component. And a list of years. Please click the link to see detail. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19N17G5Bca8rVWMtwmgsaUq774jlD4vA3pO-VwQVbIgU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You have to put the code in here. If that link becomes dead, then the information is useless to future coders.

Comment: Just edit the question @Tony Drummond.

Comment: Get a reference to your HTML element and use `element.scrollIntoView()` .